# Moving specific collections from mongodb atlas to archive db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

*I did my homework before posting this question*

So the case is that I want to create a utility in my nodejs application that will move specific collections from my main database to an archive database and vice versa. I am using mongo db atlas for my application. I have been doing my research and I found two possible ways one is to create a mongodump and store and other is to create a backup file myself using my node application and upload it to archive db. Using the later approach will cause to loose my collection indexes.

I am planning to use mongodump for the purpose but can't find a resource that shows how to achieve that. Any help would be appreciated. Also if any one has any experience with similar situation I am open to suggestions as well.

Comment: See [Backup and Restore Atlas Cluster Data](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/backup-restore-cluster/) in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently created a mongodump & mongorestore wrapper for nodejs: [node-mongotools](https://github.com/boly38/node-mongotools)

What does it mean?

you have to install mongo binary on your host by following official mongo documentation([example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)) and then, you could use node-mongotools to call them from nodeJS.

Here is an example but tool doc contains more details:

```
  var mt = new MongoTools();
  const dumpResult = await mt.mongodump({ uri, path })
    .catch(console.log);
```